# Comparing the files in two directories (recursively) when the file structure has changed

Tags: linux, bash, backup

I have accidentally deleted part of folder (before stopping the rm command). However, the backup I restored was around 2 weeks old, and unfortunately, I've renamed and restructured the directories between deleting them and the point in time of the backup. I have manually restored what I know was missing, but I'm not sure I managed to catch everything.

Is there a fast method of showing file differences that do not include their parent directories, only file name and modification or creation date? For example, I have the directories

```
data/output/test1/file1.mha
```

which I might have moved/renamed to

```
data/results/mhas/first_test/file1.mha
```

Using `diff -rq` did not work for this and is also rather slow. The directory has a size of around 2TB and a fairly large number of files, so checking the MD5 of every files is barely an option.

---

To clarify a little bit, after restoring the backup, I have:

```
/data_backup_restore/output/test1/file1.mha
```

and

```
/data/results/mhas/first_test/file1.mha
```

since the restored backup still uses the 'old' directory structure. I've changed it because it was a mess, but I haven't written down all changes/renames I've done, since there were a lot of them.
I would consider both of the above the same if filesize, modification date and filename match.

Comment: To clarify: you have one directory with files and another directory with files. And you want to compare them?

Comment: I'd probably start with an rsync dry run

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yes, but the files are in different subdirectories

Comment: @TomYan Sorry, forgot to mention in the original post that I've also tried that with ```rsync -navi```, and while it was really fast, I could not get it to compare just the files while ignoring the path to the file

Comment: OK, do they have same names: compare `file1` with `file`? And do you want to check if the file exist in second directory or if the **same** file exist in second directory?

Comment: Yes, the files would have the same name, I've only renamed the directories they're in, not the files themselves. So if the filenames don't match there is no need to compare anything. However, there a lot of files with the same name and filesize in different directories, e.g. there are thousands of "MR.mha" across different subdirectories, so I need either the modification time or some hash sum to make sure they're the same

Comment: @RomeoNinov And sorry, but I'm not sure I understand the second question. They would be copies of one another if that's what you're asking. One that was the original and did not get deleted, and one that's the restored backup.

Comment: I get it and add answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to compare the two directories recursively, but ignoring the directory structure, so basically if you find two files in the two trees having the same filename, creation/modification time and size (you don't mention size, but I guess it will be also useful), then treat them as the same, even if they are at different positions in the two directory trees.

If this is correct, you can create a list of files with size, time and filename like this:

```
ls -lR --time-style=long-iso /data/output/  | grep ^- | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5- | sort -k 4 >files_output.txt
ls -lR --time-style=long-iso /data/results/  | grep ^- | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5- | sort -k 4 >files_results.txt
```

And then compare the two lists, either with `diff` or some GUI like `meld`.

Details:

- Using `--time-style=long-iso` to avoid locale specific peculiarities that might break the following pipes.
- `grep ^-` to only select the actual files, ignore directories and possibly other special files. Depending on your use case, you might want to add more here, e.g. symbolic links...
- `tr -s ' '` will squeeze multiple consecutive spaces for the following `cut` to work correctly in all cases.
- `cut` columns beginning from column 5 (the file size)
- `sort` to make the comparison later work. `-k 4` is not really necessary, as long as you are consistent in the two commands. `-k 4` will sort by filename which may be useful.

After you compare the two files and find differences, you will of course have to locate the file in the original directory tree, you can use `find` for this.

**Update**

Based on your comments, if you want to find the full paths for filenames that appear many times, you can do the following:

First get the list of files that are missing in your second directory, e.g. like this:

```
comm -1 -3 file_outputs.txt file_results.txt >missing_files.txt
```

Then, for each missing file use find to find the full path of the specific file:

```
cat missing_files.txt | while read size date time name
do
    find . -name "$name" -size ${size}c -newermt "$date $time" ! -newermt "$date $time +0000 +1 minutes"
done
```

Now notice that this is just a simple example and not optimal, and depending on the number of missing files it will call `find` that many times which can be slow if the directories are big as you indicated. In that case you should try to optimize it somehow (e.g. make a list of all files similar to the `ls -lR` but containing the full paths, and try to match that list with the list you found in the `missing.txt` file).

Comment: And what about same filename, same size (you do not compare sizes) but different content?

Comment: Definitely, this will not catch these. My understanding is that the OP did not want to compare content because of the big size "The directory has a size of around 2TB and a fairly large number of files, so checking the MD5 of every files is barely an option". Even without doing MD5, comparing the content would be slow (that's why the `diff -rq` from the OP was also slow, since even with the `-q` it has to compare the whole files as long as they are identical, which they will mostly be in this use case).

Comment: IMHO the situation is opposite, hashing will work faster. And will be applicable for binary files too.

Comment: Faster than `diff` or faster than `ls`? I doubt it will be faster than `diff -q` which only compares whether files differ or not, but that will depend on the actual implementation of `diff -q` (which btw also compares binary files). But my point was, that both `diff` and `md5` would be too slow to the OP, since they would have to scan through the whole 2TB disk.

Comment: This worked well and really fast, my only problem is that now I don't know where the files that are missing are located, since a lot of files have the same name. Is there a way to also print the full path to each file but ignore it while comparing the original outputs?

Comment: If finding by size is enough, you can `find . -name <filename> -size <size>c` to get the location (based on the filename and size you got from the diff. If you have many files with same size and name, then you need to somehow add the timestamp to your `find` too. The easiest I can come up with that is scriptable would be this (with `$name`, `$size` `$date` and `$time` having the values from the ls output): `find . -name $name -size ${size}c -newermt "$date $time" ! -newermt "$date $time +0000 +1 minutes"`. Of course, you have to be careful with e.g. spaces in filenames and similar.

Comment: Files with the same name will 9/10 times have the same size and there will be around >100 of each, so the first one is not an option. I'm also having trouble getting the second suggestion to work, so excuse the dumb question but how would I go about saving `$name`, `$date`, `$time` as variables? Would I have to loop over all lines in the difference file?

Comment: I updated my answer to show an example for how to look over the missing files and search for the full path of each, but this may be slow since it has to loop over the whole directory structure for each missing file.

Answer (score 0):

To compare file contents, you could use the following commands:

```
find FolderA -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cksum > FoldA.cksum
find FolderB -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cksum > FoldB.cksum
```

You may sort the two files together. As the first two fields are
checksum and size, you may ignore groups of two that have the same
checksum and size.
Groups of one denote a missing file in one folder.

Source :
[Compare large directories recursively - but ignoring sub-directories - compare two backups - with gui](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564177/compare-large-directories-recursively-but-ignoring-sub-directories-compare-t).

Comment: IMHO CRC (default for above command) is quite weak as hash and you may see good amount of collisions.

Comment: @RomeoNinov: It's easy enough to test. It would be interesting if the poster could do some comparative tests. I never saw checksum collisions, but I haven't used it extensively.

Comment: I've tried both this and the the sha1sum version, but both seem to be far too slow and were hogging too many resources, so I had to stop them. However, it's 'only' 155k files in total, so a collision seems unlikely to me? I'm sorry if my original post made it seem like much more, it's just that most things I had tried did take surprisingly much longer than ls and I didn't know how many files there were myself.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use hashes:

```
cd /directory1
sha1sum * **/* >/tmp/sum
cd /directory2
sha1sum -c /tmp/sum
```

The odd construction `**/*` is to search in subdirectories (`globbing` should be enabled) this will generate hash of files in first directory and check it with the hash in second directory with indication about OK file and missing/mismatch hash:

```
#a/aa: OK
rr: OK
zzz: FAILED
sha1sum: WARNING: 1 of 3 computed checksums did NOT match
```

P.S. Do not be afraid of using hash functions, they are quite fast

Comment: Thanks, something like this should work. I assume sha1sum is faster than cksum suggested harrymc?

Comment: @muffinname, I am not sure, but AFAIK the default hash of `cksum` is CRC which create more probabilities for collision (different files with same hash). W/o tests I am 99% sure `cksum` with CRC is faster than `sha1sum` :)